# Scala UDF fails when called from a SELECT statement in DataBricks / Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, azure-databricks

I have the following Scala function that I've registered as UDF in Azure DataBricks (Spark 2.3.1 and Scala 2.11):

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime

val slot = (dt : DateTime) => { 
  var _s : Int = (dt.dayOfYear().get() - 1) * 24 + dt.hourOfDay().get()
  _s  
}

val compute_slot = (t: String, offset: Int) => {
  var dt:DateTime = DateTime.parse(t) 
  ((Set(slot(dt)) ++ Set(slot(dt.minusSeconds(offset)))) ++ Set(slot    (dt.plusSeconds(offset)))).toArray  
}

    spark.udf.register("get_slot", compute_slot)
```

The function works well if called directly...

```
compute_slot("2018-11-01T05:04:33.827+0000", 1800)
```

...or as UDF in SQL:

```
%sql
SELECT explode(get_slot(cast("2018-11-01T05:04:33.827+0000" as string), 1800))
```

When using the UDF within a SparkSql SQL query…

```
%sql
SELECT * FROM tab LATERAL VIEW explode(get_slot(cast(timestamp as string), 1800)) my_view
```

… or

```
val ColUDF = udf(compute_slot)
df.withColumn("arr", ColUDF($"timestamp", lit(1800))).show()
```

it fails with the following error message. It mentions a wrong date format, that confuse me as the function works well outside the SELECT statement over my table.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 177.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 177.0 (TID 33992, 10.139.64.4, executor 4): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$2: (string, int) => array<int>)

at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.encodeUnsafeRows(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$$anonfun$2.apply(Collector.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$$anonfun$2.apply(Collector.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:384)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2018-11-01 05:04:33.827" is malformed at " 05:04:33.827"
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:945)
    at org.joda.time.DateTime.parse(DateTime.java:160)
    at org.joda.time.DateTime.parse(DateTime.java:149)
    at line7c3ca3974ac14b88a9a351882d40a949342.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$2.apply(command-1611582591913421:11)
    at line7c3ca3974ac14b88a9a351882d40a949342.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$2.apply(command-1611582591913421:10)
    ... 12 more
```

Any help to focus what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Paolo

Comment: It seems to be very clear in the error output that your timestamp is malformed. You gave it `2018-11-01 05:04:33.827` when it seems to work with the string you provided before: `2018-11-01T05:04:33.827+0000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `parse` uses [`ISODateTimeFormat`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTimeParser()) with pattern defined as:

> ```
> datetime          = time | date-opt-time
> time              = 'T' time-element [offset]
> date-opt-time     = date-element ['T' [time-element] [offset]]
> date-element      = std-date-element | ord-date-element | week-date-element
> std-date-element  = yyyy ['-' MM ['-' dd]]
> ord-date-element  = yyyy ['-' DDD]
> week-date-element = xxxx '-W' ww ['-' e]
> time-element      = HH [minute-element] | [fraction]
> minute-element    = ':' mm [second-element] | [fraction]
> second-element    = ':' ss [fraction]
> fraction          = ('.' | ',') digit+
> offset            = 'Z' | (('+' | '-') HH [':' mm [':' ss [('.' | ',') SSS]]])
> ```

while your date doesn't contain `offset` component. To match `2018-11-01 05:04:33.827` you should provide a format:

```
scala> import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
scala> DateTime.parse("2018-11-01 05:04:33.827", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
res3: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2018-11-01T05:04:33.827+01:00
```

Comment: This fixed the problem. I totally missed it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The column `timestamp` is not formatted correctly. It says in the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2018-11-01 05:04:33.827" is malformed at " 05:04:33.827"

Furthermore this failed:

```
get_slot(cast(timestamp as string), 1800)
```

But this succeeded:

```
get_slot(cast("2018-11-01T05:04:33.827+0000" as string), 1800)
```

So your `timestamp` column is simply not formatted properly. Just add the `T` part, and you'll be fine.